# How can two arrays created in the same way become different?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

The var_dumps of the two arrays are different but they were created the exact same way .  Why is this?????

first array dump:

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
   string(6)     ",2,2,1"
 }
```

second array dump:

```
array(3) {
 [0]=>
 array(0) {
 }
 [1]=>
 string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
 }
```

array 1 is made on fileA.php

```
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
 {

    $iState[] = $row["state"];
 }///end while
```

then i use ajax to send to fileB.php

```
   js_array=<? echo json_encode($iState); ?>;

   var url_js_array=js_array.join(',');

    xmlhttp.open("GET","fileB.php?istate="+ url_js_array,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

then in fileB.php(ajax response file) i retrieve the array

```
    $iStateValues[] =$_GET["istate"] ;
```

then I create array 2 on fileB.php

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {

     $currentiState[]= $row["state"];

      }///end while
```

then I compred the two

```
   echo"\n\nsame test\n";
   if($iStateValues==$currentiState)
   echo "same";
   else
   echo "not same";
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

Currently, you're sending the comma-separated string to `fileB.php`.

```
$iStateValues[] = $_GET["istate"] ;
```

`$_GET["istate"]` contains the comma-separated string, and in the above statement, you're pushing the value into an empty array `$iStateValues`.

Now, in `fileB.php`, you create another array `$currentiState` using a `while` loop. Then you try to compare them.

`$iStateValues` is a string, **not an array**. `$currentiState` is a real array. So the comparison will always return `FALSE`.

**How to fix the issue:**

Instead of sending the comma-separated string to `fileB.php`, send the actual JSON string. So your code will look like:

```
js_str=<? echo json_encode($iState); ?>;
xmlhttp.open("GET","fileB.php?istate="+ js_str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Now, in `fileB.php`, you can receive the JSON string and then decode it, like so:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($_GET['istate'], true);
```

(The second parameter in `JSON` decode says it should be decoded to an associative array instead of an object).

Then do the comparison.

Comment: Sorry Type o,  when i added the "$jsonArray = json_decode($_GET['istate'], true);" line i cannot get access to the array... i tried to print it and nothing....

Comment: example: $jsonArray = json_decode($_GET["istate"], true);



echo"otherside\n";
 $length = count($jsonArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
echo $jsonArray[$i];
}

Comment: @codenamejupiterx: `print_r($_GET);` -- do you see the JSON string there?

Comment: `$jsonArray = json_decode($_GET["istate"], true); print_r($jsonArray);` -- how about now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43718/discussion-between-amal-murali-and-codenamejupiterx)